# var sizeBoolean=$("a #sizeId:not(:empty)");

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="price-holder">
        <div class="multiple-price">
          <div class="sale">Sale $179.99 </div>
          <div class="original">Regular $199.99 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swatch-container-new">
            <div class="swatch active" ><a href="#" title="Blue" rel="1107910_Blue.jpeg" class="swatch-color color20"></a></div>
            <div class="swatch" ><a id="colorId" href="#" title="Purple"  rel="1107910_Purple.jpg" class="swatch-color color1"></a></div>
            <div class="swatch" ><a id="colorId" href="#" title="Turquoise" rel="1107910_Turquoise.jpeg" class="swatch-color color17"></a></div>
            <div class="swatch" ><a id="colorId" href="#" title="Green" rel="1107910_Green.jpg" class="swatch-color color22"></a></div>
            <div class="swatch" ><a id="colorId" href="#" title="Pink" rel="1107910_Hot_Pink.jpeg" class="swatch-color color14"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My jQuery part:

```
var colorBoolean=$("a #colorId:not(:empty)");
alert(colorBoolean);
```

When I executed this in jQuery it was alerting as [object Object].  How do I check if sizeBoolean has true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a boolean

```
var colorBoolean = $("a #colorId:not(:empty)").length > 0
```

At the moment you're simply returning a jQuery object, to check it's existence, check the `length`